# Scheduled Python programming with input if results are found

Tags: python, popup, schedule

I have a program which I run right now using a batch file from the Run command. However, I wish for this program to run at scheduled times in the background and if it gets a specific result (based on web-scraped data)  it should give a pop-up after which it is possible to retrieve information from a shelf file opened in the Python script. If the specific result has not been found it can simply exit the program.

I know that it can be scheduled using the Task Scheduler. I also know how to get user input and process the shelf file information.

Is the Task Scheduling a "nice" solution,
how could I get a pop-up, and
how can I also close the Command Prompt from Python (so no `sys.exit()`) ?

Answer (score 1):

The task scheduler is acceptable but not the nice solution. From my perspective the nice solution (as I understand you talking about Windows OS) will prepare the service that will execute the required tasks. 
You may create such service even in python. For that you can use [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) the special python library for Windows. You can take a look on this [code](https://gist.github.com/drmalex07/10554232) for the service implementation.